# How to get a location continuously by link click at once

Tags: javascript, php, mobile, geolocation

I am trying to get the mobile user location by URL access. With the PHP *$_SERVER* variable I can get ipv4/ipv6 address, but the results are less accurate.

> with the one click of user javascript can send a client location. but
>   it's asks for the user permission, it's fine. but after the one click,
>   expecting to get a location continuously, even the browser is not
>   active

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use [web worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers).

A web worker is a JavaScript that runs in the background, independently of other scripts, without affecting the performance of the page. You can continue to do whatever you want: clicking, selecting things, etc., while the web worker runs in the background.

Nowaday [PWAs](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/codelabs/your-first-pwapp/) use service workers (a kind of web workers) for getting notifications even when the apps are closed.

Comment: If you want to learn more about service workers, have a look here: https://dev.to/paco_ita/service-workers-and-caching-strategies-explained-step-3-m4f , where I also introduce caching strategies to improve the app performance.

Comment: thank you, 'web worker' is exact one, what i am searching for

Answer (score 1):

You can invoke the following code in your PWAs in the starting page. So that each time the users opens it by following the link you provide, the app will get her/his position:

```
function getLocation() {

  // Check if the current device support geoLocation
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos) {
      console.log("Latitude: " + pos.coords.latitude +
        "Longitude: " + pos.coords.longitude);
    });
  } else {
  // Geolocation is not supported by the
  }
}
```

Here the [MSDN Docs about Gelocation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/getCurrentPosition).